# Select * instead of table.* from active record queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I am building a rather complicated query, and I'd like to stick to active record methods as much as possible (because there are lots of optional scopes from the model to add later on).

Current code:

```
join_sql = "INNER JOIN(SELECT username, user_id FROM external_credentials UNION SELECT username, user_id FROM internal_credentials) ON id = user_id"

User.joins(join_sql)
```

This produces the following SQL:

```
SELECT  "USERS".* FROM "USERS" INNER JOIN(SELECT username, user_id FROM external_credentials UNION SELECT username, user_id FROM internal_credentials) ON id = user_id FETCH FIRST :a1 ROWS ONLY  [["LIMIT", 11]]
```

The problem is it's selecting `"USERS".*` instead of just `*`, so I can't use the extra fields I'm joining on. How do I tell ActiveRecord to accept all the fields of the join as well?

Comment: This should do `User.joins(join_sql).select("*")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `SELECT "USERS".*` is the result of invoking `joins` (or some other methods) in an ApplicationRecord object. When not explicitly told what columns from what tables to select, it'll take all the columns from the table the model being accessed belongs to.

You can modify them just by *overriding* the select statement:

```
User.joins(join_sql).select('<whatever you need here>')
```